# How to create multiple indexes in logstash.conf file?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I used the following piece of code to create an index in logstash.conf

```
output {  
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}  
    elasticsearch {  
        host => "localhost"  
        protocol => "http"  
        index => "trial_indexer"   
    }
}
```

To create another index i generally replace the index name with another in the above code. Is there any way of creating many indexes in the same file? I'm new to ELK.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use a pattern in your index name based on the value of one of your fields. Here we use the value of the `type` field in order to name the index:

```
output {  
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}  
    elasticsearch {  
        host => "localhost"  
        protocol => "http"  
        index => "%{type}_indexer"   
    }
}
```

You can also use several `elasticsearch` outputs either to the same ES host or to different ES hosts:

```
output {  
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}  
    elasticsearch {  
        host => "localhost"  
        protocol => "http"  
        index => "trial_indexer"   
    }
    elasticsearch {  
        host => "localhost"  
        protocol => "http"  
        index => "movie_indexer"   
    }
}
```

Or maybe you want to route your documents to different indices based on some variable:

```
output {  
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
    if [type] == "trial" {
        elasticsearch {  
            host => "localhost"  
            protocol => "http"  
            index => "trial_indexer"   
        }
    } else {
        elasticsearch {  
            host => "localhost"  
            protocol => "http"  
            index => "movie_indexer"   
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The syntax has changed a little bit in Logstash 2 and 5:

```
output {  
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
    if [type] == "trial" {
        elasticsearch {  
            hosts => "localhost:9200"  
            index => "trial_indexer"   
        }
    } else {
        elasticsearch {  
            hosts => "localhost:9200"  
            index => "movie_indexer"   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you referring to the "type" declared in "input" section? if so , is there a way to use as index one of the fields in actual redis event I'm logging?

Comment: @Kepedizer `type` can be defined anywhere, whether in the input section or the filter section. The only issue [in your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531883/logstash-wont-pass-index-from-redis) is a typo, you need to use `%{index}` instead of `${index}`

Comment: @Val I was having a terrible time trying to track down the answer to this in the Logstash docs, so thank you very much for clearing it up. Score another one for StackOverflow.

Comment: `if [type] == "trial" && [msg] == "yes"` can i use and condition in output?? @Val

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN yes definitely