# Step-by-step guide for creating index?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash

I'm looking for a guide to create a index in elasticsearch, but it is not as simple as the guide given at:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

It seems pretty simple what I want to do but I just can't seem to get it working. Now, I want my index to be daily indices (same as the default logstash index) but with some changes. These changes includes a name change and a specific mapping for fields which have specific types. Now I know that I have to specify in the output-elasticsearch section in the logstash configuration that:

```
index => "name-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
```

The only information I found was that an index can be created based on a template and I tried creating the template but still nothing happens.

Creating the template I used the following:

```
PUT _template/ids
{
"template": "ids-*", 
"order":    0, 
"settings": {
"index": {
  "number_of_shards": 5,
  "number_of_replicas": 1
},
"mappings": {
  "log": {
    "_all": {
      "enabled": true,
      "omit_norms": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
      },
      "@version": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "field1": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "field2": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
```

Comment: Can you provide more information like commands used for `index-creation` and `template-creation` ?

Comment: For the `template-creation` I used the following command with some settings included: `PUT _template/ids
{
  "template": "ids-*", 
  "order":    0, 
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 5,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
  "mappings": {...`. If I run this command I get results that it is accepted but going forward is where I got stuck.

Comment: I can't see your full command for some reason. Can you update your question with full command. However if you once create template successfully then you can test that by creating test index with patter `ids-*` for example `ids-test`.

Comment: I updated the question. I also tried our your suggestion, and it worked creating something like `ids-test`. But how would I then change it so that it creates that index daily?

Comment: did `ids-test` index get all settings and mappings provided in index-pattern?

Comment: No it doesn't look like it, so I might have done something wrong. If I created the template correctly, what would be the next step?

Comment: It seems you are including mappings element in settings in template json. But they are two different elements. Regarding daily index creation, how are you indexing docs into ES? using logstash or java?

Comment: I am using logstash. What elements do you mean?

Comment: I hope following link will help you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820478/how-to-create-multiple-indexes-in-logstash-conf-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For daily indices with "some changes" it is nice to use templates.

To check which templates are already set in the cluster use:

```
GET {es_url}/_template
```

To set new template to the cluster use:

```
PUT {es_url}/_template/ids
{
"template": "ids-*", 
"order":    0, 
"settings": {
"index": {
  "number_of_shards": 5,
  "number_of_replicas": 1
},
"mappings": {
  "log": {
    "_all": {
      "enabled": true,
      "omit_norms": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
      },
      "@version": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "field1": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "field2": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}}}
```

To delete an exsisting template use:

```
DELETE {es_url}/_template/{template_name}
```

If you set the "ids" template to the cluster- any document that will be inserted to the cluster, to index with name that matches "ids-*" (aka "ids-123", "ids-sheker", "ids-2016.05.02") will get the mapping of the inserted ids template.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but was unsuccessful. But it was a problem on my side because no data was being sent so the index wasn't created. After some data was sent, the template worked.